# Python Virtual Env Uses Different Module Than Installed

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, xlrd, python-venv

I have a project where a specific version of a module has to be used, xlrd 1.2.0.

With this, I'm trying to create a virtual environment and have it use 1.2.0, but it doesn't seem to be using the proper module installed once I run my program. This is how I went about starting my venv and installing xlrd 1.2.0

```
conda create --name my_env_name python=3.9
conda activate my_env_name
>>> (my_env_name) C:\Users\currDir>      //looks good
 
(my_env_name) C:\Users\currDir> pip install xlrd==1.2.0
(my_env_name) C:\Users\currDir> pip show xlrd
>>> Name: xlrd, Version: 1.2.0, ...     //venv has proper version installed
 
(my_env_name) C:\Users\currDir> py MyProgram.py    //starting program
```

So it looks like the right version is installed and the venv is up and running with the right version of xlrd, but when I put the following in my .py file and run it, the program's using the wrong version of xlrd:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(xlrd.__version__)
>>> 2.0.1
```

Why is this? I'm semi-new to venv's so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats your PATH and PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Easiest way to get that would be `import sys` and `print sys.path`

Comment: @PaulBrennan looks like an array:
` ['C:\\Users\\currDir', 
'\\styling', 
'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']`

Comment: Looks like you are using local versions (and not the system version of the software)

Comment: Agreed. No conda path. Is it possible that when `py` is called it defaults to the non-conda python environment? The `py` command is non-standard. I don't think running `py --version` would be enough to check since you have a local installation of python v3.9. Try running `python MyProgram.py`.

Comment: @Ghoti yep that was it! 'py' called the local version of Python and was grabbing the system version of xlrd (2.0.1) where 'python' calls the venv version of Python and was using the proper xlrd (1.2.0)
Thank you so so much! It works as expected now

Comment: @PaulBrennan thank you for the support!